# Input Restriction in C

Tags: c

I'm having a bit of a problem restricting the user input. I only want the integers 1,2 or 3 to be the input. Do.. while loop does the job for invalid integer inputs, but how do I disregard string/character inputs? I also need to ask the user repetitively if ever the input is invalid.

Update:

```
int problem;

printf("Please select the problem that you want to solve:\n");
printf("\t 1-Problem 1\n");
printf("\t 2-Problem 2\n");
printf("\t 3-Problem 3\n");
while( scanf("%d", &problem)==0 && (problem!=1 || problem !=3 || problem !=2))
{int c;
while((c=getchar())!='\n' && c!=EOF);
printf("Please select the problem that you want to solve:\n");
printf("\t 1-Problem 1\n");
printf("\t 2-Problem 2\n");
printf("\t 3-Problem 3\n");
}
```

It kinda looks messy because of the multiple printfs. I just don't want lengthy codes in one row. Anyway, I wanted only 1,2, or 3 as inputs. If the entered input is invalid, the program asks the user again until the user inputs a valid input.

The code works for invalid inputs such as words, letters, characters, etc. However, if the user inputs 1.2 , it proceeds with 1 which should not be the case. 0 isn't accepted either. What can I do to my code to restrict them?

Comment: How do you take the input? Can you show that code?

Comment: Reading a [`scanf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) reference could help you. Especially read what it returns.

Comment: Well,  I only used scanf and an integer declaration. That may be the problem, perhaps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`scanf` with a `%d` will fail and return 0 in case of invalid inputs(like character(s)). So, just check if the `scanf` failed by checking the return value of it.

```
while(scanf("%d",&num)==0 && (num<=1 || num >=3)) //Invalid input if this is true
{
  int c;
  while((c=getchar())!='\n' && c!=EOF); //Clear the stdin

  printf("Invalid input. Try again\n");
}
```

The line

```
while((c=getchar())!='\n' && c!=EOF);
```

clears the standard input stream so that `scanf` does not read the invalid input again and again resulting in an infinite loop.

Note that `scanf` *can* return `EOF`. This will cause the program to think that the user has entered valid input. You can add a check to see if the return value from `scanf` isn't `EOF`. Also, you should initialize `num` to a number that is not 1,2 or 3 to avoid invoking Undefined Behavior.

Comment: Followup: It accepts decimals, but it should not. Since conversion is possible between a float/double to an int, 1.2 becomes 1, and so the program accepts it. How can I prevent this from happening? 

I've tried replacing the (num<=1 || num>=3) by (num!=1 || num!=2 || num!=3) but it still accepts decimal inputs.

Comment: Scan the input as a string and parse it accordingly. Post a new question so that users will answer it.

Comment: scanf() can return values other than zero on failure.  These aren't checked for.

Comment: @Peter , Thank you. I forgot about `EOF`