# User Input Restriction goes haywire

Tags: c, validation, input

```
int problem;

printf("Please select the problem that you want to solve:\n");
printf("\t 1-Problem 1\n");
printf("\t 2-Problem 2\n");
printf("\t 3-Problem 3\n");

while( scanf("%d", &problem)==0 && (problem!=1 || problem !=3 || problem !=2))
{
  int c;
  while((c=getchar())!='\n' && c!=EOF);
  printf("Please select the problem that you want to solve:\n");
  printf("\t 1-Problem 1\n");
  printf("\t 2-Problem 2\n");
  printf("\t 3-Problem 3\n");
}
```

It kinda looks messy because of the multiple `printf`s. I just don't want lengthy codes in one row. Anyway, I wanted only 1,2, or 3 as inputs. If the entered input is invalid, the program asks the user again until the user inputs a valid input.

Sure, the code works for characters, string inputs but whenever 0, or any other integer or input starting with a number except for 1,2 and 3, the program does nothing. Also, if 1.2 is entered, 1 is chosen. same goes for 2.2, 2.3 which will become 2. How can I fix it?

Comment: `scanf("%d", &problem)==0`--> did you mean `scanf("%d", &problem)==1`?

Comment: `(problem!=1 || problem !=3 || problem !=2)` replace `||` with `&&`

Comment: I've replaced the || with &&. It worked, however, float/double inputs are still converted into their integer counterparts. Any advice?

Comment: @LeviAckerman: You're reading in a `int`. What did you expect? If you want floating point input, read in a `float` and use `%f` instead of `%d`

Comment: That's because you're reading integers. Reading stops at the first non-integer character (the `.`). You'd need to validate what's left in the stream until the next newline to decide whether you'd like to consider your input valid. I'd solve that by reading whole lines and validating with a regular expression first, if this "glitch" is really that important to you.

Comment: Use `getchar()` after the loop. If this is not equal to `\n`, the input is invalid.

Answer (score 1):

**Point 1**

You need to change the logic involved in

```
scanf("%d", &problem)==0
```

because, if `scanf()` returns `0`, then reading `problem` is [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

You need to re-think the `while` loop logic. Also, always initialize the local variables.

**Point 2**

You need to change

```
(problem!=1 || problem !=3 || problem !=2)
```

to

```
((problem!=1) && (problem !=3) && (problem !=2))
```

because, logically, you're tryning to say, *if the input is not 1 and not 2 and not 3, then...*, so,

Comment: @CoolGuy `The code repeats until a valid input.` is of least importance here. At first, if scanf fails, reading the variable value is UB.

Comment: If the user enters a character, then the loop will not execute

Comment: @CoolGuy aahh. I got your point now. My bad, edited the answer. Hope the meaning is clear now. :-)

Comment: Thanks. Everything seems to be working fine now except for the decimal to integer automatic conversion thingie. How can I prevent this from happening?

Comment: @LeviAckerman , Please initialize `problem` to something that is not 1, 2 or 3 to avoid UB(Read this answer's point1)

Comment: @SouravGhosh , Actually , it was my mistake. [I told the OP to use that](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29668414/3049655). I've edited my answer there.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code

```
while( scanf("%d", &problem)==0 && (problem<1 || problem >3))
```

It will check valid user input and also check user has entered value between 1 to 3.
condition will fail if user enter value less than 1 or greater than 3.

Comment: That would fail if I enter `4` or `12345`, since the return value of `scanf` would be 1 in these cases.

Comment: @DarkDust, yes condition will fail if user will enter any value less than 1 or greater than 3.

Comment: The problem here is when the input is a character in the first iteration, then, `(problem<1 || problem >3)` is checked. Will it be true? or false? It cannot be determined as `problem` isn't initialized.